# How to write Case statement or IF ELSE (possibly) statement within IFNULL

Tags: mysql, case, ifnull

I am trying to use Case statement or IF ELSE statement within IFNULL function to specify in more details of options.

If I uncomment the IF statement where it starts with *IF(`t`.`Type_id` IN (7777 , 9999),* it would not cause error, but when I try to use CASE statement, it gives that error (**"Select" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting '(', with**).

I am trying to use CASE statement to be more specific, but if there is any way to use IF ELSE statement to specify *`t`.`Type_id`in (4444, 2222) then 'VIDEOVISITS - RETURN'* and not causing this error, please let me know.   Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT       
    IFNULL(IF(`t`.`NRP_classification` NOT IN (
                    'NEW',
                    'TELEPHONE'),
                'OTHER NC',
                IF(
                    `t`.`NRP_classification` = 'VIDEOVISITS',
                    //Trying to replace from here: 
                    IF(`t`.`Type_id` IN (7777 , 9999),
                        'VIDEOVISITS - NEW',
                        'VIDEOVISITS - RETURN'
                       ),
                    `t`.`NRP_classification`
                    //Trying to replace until here   
                    /*
                    case `t`.`NRP_classification` = 'VIDEOVISITS'
                        when `t`.`Type_id` IN (7777 , 9999) then 'VIDEOVISITS - NEW'
                        when `t`.`Type_id` IN (4444, 2222) then 'VIDEOVISITS - RETURN'
                    end as `t`.`NRP_classification` 
                    */
                   )                     

            ),
            'OTHER NC') AS `Type`
       FROM
    ((((((((((((((SELECT 
        `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Appt_id` AS `Appt_id`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`CSN` AS `CSN`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`N` AS `N`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Date` AS `Date`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Time` AS `Time`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Len` AS `Len`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Status` AS `Status`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Type` AS `Type`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`LOS` AS `LOS`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Made_date` AS `Made_date`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Rescheduled` AS `Rescheduled`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`SD_canceled` AS `SD_canceled`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Canc_date` AS `Canc_date`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Canc_reason` AS `Canc_reason`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`CI_startTime` AS `CI_startTime`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`CI_endTime` AS `CI_endTime`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`VS_startTime` AS `VS_startTime`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`AVS_time` AS `AVS_time`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Encounter_status` AS `Encounter_status`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`EncClosure_provID` AS `EncClosure_provID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Cosign_provID` AS `Cosign_provID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`PrimaryDx_ICD10` AS `PrimaryDx_ICD10`
    FROM
        `DONI_db`.`appointment`
    WHERE
        `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Type` NOT IN ('2100' , '4493', '5044', '5045', '5183', '5225')
            AND `DONI_db`.`appointment`.`Date` >= '2016-07-01')) `appt`
    JOIN `DONI_db`.`type` `t`)
    JOIN `DONI_db`.`appt_status` `as`)
    LEFT JOIN `DONI_db`.`user` `ulos` ON (`appt`.`LOS_authProviderID` = `ulos`.`User_id`))
    JOIN (SELECT 
        `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_apptID` AS `APDS_apptID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_provID` AS `APDS_provID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_deptID` AS `APDS_deptID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_specID` AS `APDS_specID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_posID` AS `APDS_posID`
    FROM
        `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`
    WHERE
        `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_type` = 'New') `apds_np`)
    JOIN `DONI_db`.`department` `d`)
    JOIN `DONI_db`.`specialty` `s`)
    JOIN `DONI_db`.`user` `unp`)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        `apds_op`.`APDS_apptID` AS `APDS_apptID`,
            `apds_op`.`APDS_provID` AS `APDS_provID`,
            `apds_op`.`APDS_newProv` AS `APDS_newProv`,
            `uop`.`Lastname` AS `LastName`,
            `uop`.`Name` AS `Name`
    FROM
        (((SELECT 
        `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_apptID` AS `APDS_apptID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_provID` AS `APDS_provID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_posID` AS `APDS_posID`,
            `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_newProv` AS `APDS_newProv`
    FROM
        `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`
    WHERE
        `DONI_db`.`appt_pds`.`APDS_type` = 'Old')) `apds_op`
    LEFT JOIN `DONI_db`.`user` `uop` ON (`apds_op`.`APDS_provID` = `uop`.`User_id`))
    WHERE
        `uop`.`Type` = 'R'
            OR `uop`.`User_id` = 12
    GROUP BY `apds_op`.`APDS_newProv` , `apds_op`.`APDS_apptID`
    HAVING MAX(`apds_op`.`APDS_posID`)) `apds_op` ON (`apds_np`.`APDS_apptID` = `apds_op`.`APDS_apptID`
        AND `apds_np`.`APDS_posID` = `apds_op`.`APDS_newProv`))
    LEFT JOIN `DONI_db`.`clinic_dpp` `cdpp` ON ((`cdpp`.`CDPP_provID` IS NULL
        OR IF(`apds_op`.`APDS_provID` IS NULL, `apds_np`.`APDS_provID`, `apds_op`.`APDS_provID`) = `cdpp`.`CDPP_provID`)
        AND `d`.`Department_id` = `cdpp`.`CDPP_deptID`))
    LEFT JOIN `DONI_db`.`clinic` `c` ON (`cdpp`.`CDPP_clinicID` = `c`.`Clinic_id`))
    LEFT JOIN `DONI_db`.`program` `p` ON (`cdpp`.`CDPP_progID` = `p`.`Program_id`))
    JOIN `DONI_db`.`enc_status` `es`)
WHERE
    `appt`.`Type` = `t`.`Type_id`
        AND `appt`.`Status` = `as`.`ApptStatus_id`
        AND `appt`.`Appt_id` = `apds_np`.`APDS_apptID`
        AND `apds_np`.`APDS_deptID` = `d`.`Department_id`
        AND `apds_np`.`APDS_specID` = `s`.`Specialty_id`
        AND `apds_np`.`APDS_provID` = `unp`.`User_id`
        AND `appt`.`Encounter_status` = `es`.`ES_id`
        AND `d`.`toExclude` = 0
```

[image]

Comment: This code is part of another statement. Post full statement in text format.

Comment: I just posted the text version of code. Thanks.

Comment: "Post full statement" ... what you did is not full statement.

Comment: Yes you did but what is there before that part? The error points to IFNULL, so apart from the syntactical errors in this part, which (I believe) are not responsible for the error you get, there must be something wrong in the previous part.

Comment: The statement after `IFNULL` makes no sense, it is unclear what it should do, and it has errors.

Comment: I put the full statement (with a lot of long line on the bottom). It appears that error is now focusing on 'expecting '(' .